# How to I point Cloudflare to my ELB on Amazon?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm trying to point Cloudflare to my ELB on Amazon, but haven't found any good information about how to do this.

The closest I found is this page: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168986-How-do-I-add-a-Amazon-ELB-Elastic-Load-Balancing-record-to-Cloudflare- - But it mentions about adding a sub domain.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Right there in the docs you linked to: "With Cloudflare's CNAME Flattening, using a CNAME at the root or apex record is supported in an RFC-compliant manner, so it's fine to use a CNAME at the root to point to an Elastic Load Balancer."

Comment: As @ceejayoz says, it's simply a CNAME.